# Reading multiple files and arrays

Tags: python

I need to read the values from text files into an arrays, Z. This works fine using just a single file, ChiTableSingle, but when i try to use multiple files it fails. It seems to be reading lines correctly, and produces Z, but gives z[0] as just [], then i get the error, setting an array element with a sequence.

This is my current code:

```
rootdir='C:\users\documents\ChiGrid'
fileNameTemplate = r'C:\users\documents\ContourPlots\Plot{0:02d}.png'

for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for count, file in enumerate(files):

        fh=open(os.path.join(subdir,file),'r')
        #fh = open( "ChiTableSingle.txt" );

        print 'file is '+ str(file)

        Z = []
        for line in fh.readlines():
            y = [value for value in line.split()]
            Z.append( y )

        print Z[0][0]
        fh.close()

        plt.figure() # Create a new figure window

        Temp=open('TempValues.txt','r')
        lineTemp=Temp.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(lineTemp)):
            lineTemp[i]=[float(lineTemp[i])]

        Grav=open('GravValues2.txt','r')
        lineGrav=Grav.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(lineGrav)):
            lineGrav[i]=[float(lineGrav[i])]

        X,Y = np.meshgrid(lineTemp, lineGrav) # Create 2-D grid xlist,ylist values

        plt.contour(X, Y, Z,[1,2,3], colors = 'k', linestyles = 'solid')
        plt.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
        plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that your list comprehension `y = [value for ...]` is only going to return a list of strings (from the `split()` function), so you will want to convert them to a numeric format at some point before trying to plot it.

In addition, if the files you are reading in are simply white-space delimited tables of numbers, you should consider using `numpy.loadtxt(fh)` since it takes care of splitting and type conversion and returns a 2-d `numpy.array`. You can also add comment text that it will ignore if the line starts with the regular python comment character (e.g. `# this line is a comment and will be ignored`).

Just another thought, I would be careful about using variable names that are the same as a python method (e.g. the word `file` in this case). Once you redefine it as something else, the previous definition is gone.

Comment: it is all working fine for a single file using y=[...], would i still need to convert to float or something first anyway? I have also tried np.loadtxt, but that was saying there was no attribute readlines etc.